# Render an inline-block (with no text content) element inline with text

Tags: html, css

I have inline-block elements. These are glyphs and can contain SVG content, but don't contain text.

The problem is that these elements don't line up with text:

```css
.example {
    line-height: 32px;
    margin: 12px 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
}

.wrapper > .content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3px;
    right: 3px;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class=example>
    <div class=wrapper>
        <div class=content>

        </div>
    </div>
    not aligned with text
    <div class=wrapper>
        <div class=content>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I can shift down individual elements easily enough, but it's messy and requires lots of micro tweaking.

I can't rely on the line height and icon size being identical, and the SVG inside are overlaid, which requires absolute positioning.

Is there a way to make these consistently vertically centre with text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Specify `vertical-align:bottom` to wrapper class :

```css
.example {
    line-height: 24px;
    margin: 12px 0;
}

.wrapper {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 24px;
    width: 24px;
    position: relative;
    background-color: red;
    vertical-align:bottom;
}

.wrapper > .content {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 3px;
    right: 3px;
    height: 12px;
    width: 12px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class=example>
    <div class=wrapper>
        <div class=content>

        </div>
    </div>
    aligned with text
    <div class=wrapper>
        <div class=content>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```